# Does Konohamaru know how to use Sage mode?

Tags: boruto

As you can see Jiraiya, Minato and Naruto summoning jutsu is a toad, also these people also know how to use Sage mode.

How about Konohamaru? In the boruto series, I see he have 2 different summoning jutsu, one is Enra (Little Monkey) and another one is Gamagoro (Toad).

[image]
[image]

So does he have the ability to use Sage? Since he have the contact with the toad, he also have the chance to learn sage mode in the Mount Myōboku right?

***ALLOWED SPOILER!**

Comment: Nowhere it's mentioned that he has learned to use sage mode, nor does it ever mention that he has to. It's up to the shinobi to learn it or not.